# Предсказать какое из двух чисел массива выпадет следующим - 1 или 0

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Допустим  есть динамические массивы состоящие из множества элементов,

но из двух значений - один и ноль,

с разной последовательностью, но с равным количеством единиц и нулей (50 % - 1 и 50% - 0)

например (1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1...)

Для лучшего понимания: массив это статистика сыгранных игр, где 1 - это выигрыш, 0 это проигрыш.

Как предсказать след число(результат), которое добавится в массив, на основе плотности чисел (допустим последние значения массива 1,1,1,1,0 то следовательно след. число по логике должно быть 0) и/или какой шаг  выбрать чтобы, допустим на дистанции в несколько десятков чисел, суммарное число единиц(выигрышей) было бы больше чем нулей(проигрышей)? например делать выборку через одно число или через два числа, или сначала через одно, а потом через три?

пример шага через одно число:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

единиц тут сейчас больше, но на дистанции будет 50%, а нужно хотя бы 60-70%

Comment: Если мы принимаем гипотезу что последовательные значения образуют случайную последовательность, то ничего сделать нельзя. Значения случайной последовательности **независимы**. Это значит что следующее значение нельзя предсказать по предыдущим. Точка.

Comment: Если величины не независимы, то лучшее что вы можете сделать - это составить большую матрицу, в которой строка из, скажем, 21 последовательного значения. Затем натренировать нейронную сеть по двадцати значениям предсказывать двадцать первое. Если такая связь есть, то нейронная сеть её обнаружит и построит нужный вам предсказатель.

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

Если это действительно "но с равным количеством единиц и нулей (50 % - 1 и 50% - 0)" -  то это эквивалентно подбрасыванию монеты. Логика нам подсказывает, что монета не знает памяти, а азы теории вероятности говорят о том, что каждый следующий результат никак не зависит от предыдущих.

И если у вас было хоть сто нулей подряд, то следующим может выпасть равновероятно 0 или 1 (если монета, конечно, честная). Для новичков это может казаться не очевидным, но в любом учебнике по Теорверу это разжевывается детально и с примерами.

Однако, если это `"статистика сыгранных игр, где 1 - это выигрыш, 0 это проигрыш" и это результаты игр двух команд, то скорее всего тут не будет шансов "50 на 50", и вот тогда можно заняться "предсказанием" результатов следующего матча. Но -  только в вероятностном смысле.  Собственно, на этом и построен бизнес букмекерских контор.

Comment: А в случае если 60% - 1 и 40% - 0?

Comment: @pobeda Попробуйте угадать.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что результативность 50/50 оказывается на бесконечном числе подбрасываний. В реальности же, когда число подбрасываний мало, то распределение может быть любое (даже 100/0). Однако вероятность выпадения подряд 0 или 1 с каждым разом уменьшается. Но и это не означает, что если 0 выпал 10 раз подряд, то 11 обязательно будет 1.

Comment: @pobeda а в случае 60 на 40, вероятность выигрыша будет равна 60, а проигрыша 40. Еще раз -  вероятность! Т.е. ставя бесконечное число раз на 1 вы будете угадывать немного чаще, чем ошибаться. Только и всего.

Comment: Это не результаты игр двух команд, это результаты каперов, которые в целях рекламы  держат процент выигрыша 50 %

Comment: На сколько я понял, "капперы" -  это такие мошенники: https://bookmaker-ratings.ru/wiki/kappery-i-ih-zertvy/. Соответственно, они могут ставить 1 или 0 в зависимости от собственного желания. Угадывание мыслей другого человека  -  ну никак не связано ни с алгоритмами, ни с теорией вероятностей.

Comment: Эти проверенные лично мной на протяжении тысяч прогнозов. Они профи, но только проплаченные для заманухи. Невозможно держать 50% на протяжении 22.000 прогнозов и не спустится.

Comment: @pobeda Когда встречаешь кого-либо, кто просто горит желание спустить на ветер свои деньги -  лучше отойти в сторону. Вы проверили это на тысяче прогнозов, а я верю теории вероятности, которую проверили десятки тысяч людей на миллионах примеров. Но если это вас ни в чем не убеждает - продолжайте искать волшебный алгоритм. Имеете право, деньги-то ваши..

Comment: @  ArchDemo "Однако вероятность выпадения подряд 0 или 1 с каждым разом уменьшается." -  нет. Не верно в корне. Монета не имеет памяти, и не знает, сколько раз до этого и каким боком она выпадает. Поэтому вероятность выпадения каждого следующего броска будет одной и той-же, и равной 50% (для честной монеты). Это основы теории вероятностей.